# Mobile First Joomla 3 Design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I was looking to design a template in Joomla 3 using Bootstrap and was wondering how I would go about designing the template just for the smartphone. I have heard of 'Mobile First' and was wondering if this is the best way to put the template together or is it better to start larger and work my way down?

I am guessing if i start with Mobile First then I would need to create the styles within the media queries i.e. 320/480px for mobiles..

If somebody could please advise, would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's always a good idea starting with a free joomla framework so that you can concentrate your job on web design.

Frameworks like helix3, T3, Gantry5 are already responsive (free to use also for commercial purpose).

Also try this link http://www.joomlashine.com/joomla-extensions/jsn-mobilize-joomla-mobile-extension.html

I didn't use it, just tested, it makes a mobile version of your website.

There are lot of tools that you can use to create your own template,

hope it helps,
Marco